# Disable sorting for specific row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a row that computes total and it is not included on databinding. And, I dont' wanna include that row during sort event (column header click).

How to disable sorting of last row in datagridview by user (by clicking on column headers) ?

Comment: Don't put total in the grid view. What you are showing for other columns in the row for total.

Comment: Subscribe to to `Sorting` event and change the order manually or implement a custom comparer for your datatype

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15782053/1271037

Comment: [Add new row to sorted datagridview c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969370/add-new-row-to-sorted-datagridview-c-sharp)